Issues in the proof of $A_{TM}$ reducidability to $_{}$
I'm studying reducidability in Sipser Book and watching his videos, but I couldn't fully understand  his proof of $A_{TM}$  reducidability to $_{}$ (p. 218, 3rd ed).
Consider this extract:
M1 = “On input x:

If x $\neq$ w, reject .
If x $=$ w, run M on input w and accept if M does.”

Where comes the input "x"? is the same input "w"? who will inform "x" to the M1 machine? will be S machine? If is S, will be the w?
If one could construct this machine, could this solve the $A_{TM}$ as well? Thus, would be this machine undecidable in first place? Would this fact invalidate the proof of $_{}$  undecidability?

(reducidability you're losing me.) Effective line breaks in markdown: append two blanks to preceding line.
